# Running phantomjs from shell_exec with cron

Tags: cron, phantomjs, shell-exec

This is really frustrating. Simple thing like this will not work when called by crontab:

```
    $responseFull = shell_exec("phantomjs --version");
```

I must say that phantomjs works fine from terminal, for both users, normal user, *bokac* and apache user *www-data*. All I get is *null*.

Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - here's my command and it works perfectly from cron:

```
shell_exec($this->cmd . " > " . $this->statusError . " 2>&1 &");
```

As you see I don't read output but redirect it to a file - this is better for my needs, but it may be an option for you too.

Second of all - try to replace **phantomjs --version** with another command. For example: **date**. Would you receive output in this case? In case you don't - this is not a problem of phantomjs.

Cheers,
Andrey

Comment: I wasn't aware of that last part, I rederected cron to a file like you did with 2>&1 which is very convenient, and that revealed true problem which was permission problem. I am trying to sort that out now. Thanks for your help Andrey.